# How to achieve a smooth 'rain' of images in css3/jquery?

Tags: jquery, background, css-transitions

On my website I want to add an animated stream of cool/positive facebook reactions about our business. You can see my first attempt here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/809252/css3%20animation.mov

My not so good approach till now is: create a 2000x4000 png with all the reactions (files size is +3mb -> bad). And animate the background-position in loop.

What would be a smoother solution to this problem? A solution that does not have to load a 3mb image. Or anyone who found a similar effect on a specific website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filesize issues aside, such a large image can cause problems on some browsers, especially on iPad where there are maximum image dimensions (See [the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15) for details).

It would be better to split them up into individual images and pre-load them just before they become visible.

You could position them `inline-block` in a very wide `div` and use a lazy loader plugin (or write it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

So.... I like the image approach, for a couple of reasons. First, you will only need to animate a single element (the image), which will turn out faster / smoother than rendering multiple boxes in html.

[Bonus] IF you want those messages to be dynamic (i.e. so you don't have to create an image yourself), you could create a special page that renders the messages, and then point PhantomJS to it a auto-generate a PNG... which brings up another point:

You should use a PNG as the image format. It should reduce the size of the image significantly - perhaps to more like 100-500KB, instead of 3MB.

To achieve smooth animation, you should NOT use JS-based animation (i.e. jQuery's traditional methods), but rather CSS3, and do some magic to trigger hardware acceleration. For example, the following CSS3 code snippet usually triggers hardware accel to happen on the selected element:

```
#myElemToAnimate {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```